# Transition delay menu like Apple website

Tags: html, css

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RxguB/98/) , I want to have the exact transition and effect like [Apple](http://apple.com) site in mobile viewport .

so far i create something like apple , but my transition and effects are not same as apple and i think menu links in apple are fancier than mine .

```
   .in .atitel-menu-links li {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateY(0px);



        transition: transform 800ms cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1) 0ms, opacity 800ms cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1) 0ms;

    }

    .in .atitel-menu-links li:nth-child(1){
        transition-delay: 600ms;


    }
    .in .atitel-menu-links li:nth-child(2) {
        transition-delay: 800ms;

    }
   .in .atitel-menu-links li:nth-child(3) {
        transition-delay: 1s;

    }

    .in .atitel-menu-links li:nth-child(4){
        transition-delay: 1.3s;

    }
    .in .atitel-menu-links li:nth-child(5){
        transition-delay: 1.6s;

    }
```

**Updated :** 
[image]

Any help would be great ?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly does your fiddle do? What have you tried?

Comment: did u see my fiddle or just gave me a down vote ?

Comment: I didn't downvote. I checked your fiddle.

Comment: in fiddle there is a menu , that shows menu link with transition delay , like apple site

Comment: I checked this: https://fiddle.jshell.net/RxguB/98/show/light/ in Mobile mode and well as my mobile. Nothing happens. It is just a copy of bootstrap's CSS and HTML without responsiveness. Did you check it out first? Did you forget to include `responsive.min.css`?

Comment: Sorry, i updated my question with an image

Comment: Nopes, this wasn't the case for me. I cannot get this way. Are you showing the screenshot from the fiddle or the local file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87564/discussion-between-sani-and-praveen-kumar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your css code like this `

```
.atitel-menu-links li {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-10px) scale(1.7);
}
.in .atitel-menu-links li {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0px) scale(1);
    transition: transform 800ms cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1) 0ms, opacity 800ms cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1) 0ms;
}
.in .atitel-menu-links li:nth-child(1) {
    transition-delay: 70ms;
}
.in .atitel-menu-links li:nth-child(2) {
    transition-delay: 140ms;
}
.in .atitel-menu-links li:nth-child(3) {
    transition-delay: 210ms;
}
.in .atitel-menu-links li:nth-child(4) {
    transition-delay: 280ms;
}
.in .atitel-menu-links li:nth-child(5) {
    transition-delay: 350ms;
}
```

JS fiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/hLza6qa6/

though it is not exactly same as apple's menu but more near to it than yours

Comment: yes, thanks for your answer, can i ask you something ? if you test your fiddle or my fiddle in iphone 5 , you can't see links on overlay shadow !!!

Comment: well, i can't test it at the moment. but if you can show me a screenshot, may b i can help

Comment: it's all good, thanks